# How to submit a form when load page and when submit form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

If I have this:

```js
<script language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
      $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
  url: $(this).attr('action'),
  data: $(this).serialize(),

  success: function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
  }
   })        
   return false;
    });
  })
</script>
```

```html
<form name="form" id="form" method="post" action="results.php">
 <input type="text" name="date" id="date" value="2014-11-22">
 <input name="send" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Which works perfectly, how can I submit it when the page is loaded?

Comment: What is your question/ problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution that works on page load:

```
 <script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $('#form').attr('action'),
    data: $('#form').serialize(),

    success: function(data) {
      $('#result').html(data);
    }
  })        

 })
```

Comment: This one works on page load, but it does not when I hit the button

Comment: You can add this code under code that works on button click and both options will work

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

(It's submit's the form when the document is ready)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit();
});
```

To automatic submit your form use:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("form").submit();
    });
</script>
```

(But be sure your action is not on the same page!)

EDIT:

So your script should look something like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),

            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        })        


    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it just load the results.php page instead of load it inside the <div id="result"></div>

Comment: @Luis Ah you want to submit the form on page load and put the result in the div?

Comment: Exactly, (it works nice by pushing the button), and want to achieve that on page load too.

Comment: It loads the same page (the action is not the same where the form is) and now it doesn't work when I hit the button...

Comment: @Luis So you want that it direct to the results page and the insert the form into the div? (If yes do you want to see 2 forms or 1?)